# Jquery OnSubmit If Checkbox is Checked Send an Email

Tags: jquery, email, forms, checkbox, submission

I have an existing form that I would like to add email functionality to. There is a field in my form called "their email", and just under it a checkbox that asks "Send Them an email?". I would like a jquery script that would take the email from the "their email" field and email them (via an external email.php file) if the checkbox is checked. If not, completely ignore it. This would all have to take place upon submission of the form.

I currently have this:

```
if($('#checkbox').is(':checked')){
alert('It is checked');
}else{
alert('Not checked');
}
```

Just to test it out, but I cannot get it to alert either way once I submit it.

Comment: I guess it won't make sense if you do it via jQuery when on the first place you'll going to submit the form. Why in jQuery ?. You are not clear with this one.

Comment: I am using a plugin that does all of the form database entries on its own. I don't have access to this, so I want to run this email on top of it, that way when the form is submitted an email is sent, then the form does the rest of the processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re looking for [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

```
$(function() {
 $('form').submit(function() {
  if($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
   // It is checked
   $.post('email.php', { email: $('input[name=email]').val() });
  } else {
   // It’s not checked
  };
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems like it would work in theory, but I've no way to really test it. I've hooked it into my email program and submitted a test, but it doesn't seem to email. I'm guessing there is something wrong with my PHP email script. Suggestions?

Comment: That would be a separate issue with your email script. Your best bet is to close this question by marking an accepted answer, and posting a new Stack Overflow question with more details of your email script, tagged with "php form mail email" etc. Be sure to add the source of `email.php` as well!